# Can't pipe into gvim from a ruby sub process

Tags: ruby, vim

I've been attempting to use the PA_translator.vim plugin but found that it doesn't work in Win32 Gvim.  This appears to be because in an embedded Vim Ruby script it's not possible to use any of the commands which pipe in from a subprocess.  The original process builds a command dymanically and then launches a subprocess to obtain a JSON snippet like so:

```
cmd = "require 'net/http'; p Net::HTTP.get('%s', '%s')"% [host, path]
response = `ruby -e "#{cmd}"`
```

If I run this in a command line ruby script it works fine, but inside a Vim script the pipe appears to return an empty string..

I've also tried several other methods which produce the same result:

```
response = ''
IO.popen("ruby.exe", "w+") do |f|
    f.write cmd
    f.close_write
    response = f.read
    p response
end
```

And even:

```
def redirect
    orig_defout = $stdout
    $stdout = StringIO.new
    yield
    $stdout.string
ensure
    $stdout = orig_defout
end

response = redirect { eval cmd }
```

All of these seem to fail for the same reason, it's not possible to get the output from the pipe and I get back an empty string.  GVim is a true win32 process, is there some reason why piping from a subprocess won't work?

**EDIT**: If I try to capture piped output from embedded vim/perl, that works fine, so I guess it's some particular issue with the vim -> win32 -> ruby combination:

```
fun! SayHello()
perl << EOF
    $bob = `ls`;
    VIM::Msg($bob);
EOF
```

endfun

Comment: I don't see how this is related to GVim at all? Do these scripts work when run as standalone?

Comment: Also, why are you opening an external Ruby process from inside Ruby? That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @NiklasB As I said in my question, it does work in a standalone script it only fails in an embedded ruby gvim session.

Comment: As for why invoke ruby from ruby, this is really down to the author of the PA_translator.vim plugin.  However, it's not that odd is it?  It's just the same as eval.

Comment: Yeah, eval is also useless most of the time ;) You could just as well run the script inline, but anyway: Maybe your Ruby binary is not found due to PATH issues? Have you check with something simpler such as `ruby -v`?

Comment: @NiklasB. Sadly it's not that simple, ruby is on my path and I can invoke it and make it write to a file for example.  I simply can't pipe any output back from it.

Comment: As a side note, the author seems to have used this eval like method because the web service actually generates data which is parseable by ruby...  So the web service is generating code which can be evalled.

Comment: Okay, I think I get the problem now. So what Ruby environment is that script run in? What implementation does Vim use here? Is the standard Ruby installation used?

Comment: I built Win32 native GVim 7.3 against the DLL provided with Windows Ruby 1.9.3.  Ruby scripts are generally working apart from this stream problem...

Comment: Actually I'm almost ready to give up on this script and write my own (probably in perl/python which I'm more familiar with) I rewrote this part of the script earlier today to avoid using pipes only to find that the data returned from the web service now looks somewhat different than it did when this plugin was written :-(

Comment: Hm, yeah that's a tough one. I doubt that you will actually get a good answer here anyways because the problem is very localized and should be hard to reproduce. Maybe it's a real bug, in which case it will be hard to report because of the special circumstances.

Comment: Yes, I think you might be right.  Although it could be that all ruby scripting is just a bit broken on Windows Vim which would be a bug worth fixing.

Comment: The problem may be something more general than Ruby+Vim on Windows. I'm having a similar problem on Win7 32-bit and Markdown.pl. Problem isn't path related- seems like it may have to do with the way CMD deals with pipes. What VIM does doesn't work:

`cmd /c perl C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\Markdown.pl --html4tags < C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\VIiD13D.tmp > c:\c.html 2>&1`

no cmd /c and it works:

`perl C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\Markdown.pl --html4tags < C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\VIiD13D.tmp > c:\c.html 2>&1`

Comment: Also- If I stick a few random print("hola"); into the perl script before and after the bit where it prints the Markdown interpreted text those do show up- both on the command line when using cmd /c and in VIM. I was able to determine this by adding a long sleep command at the end of .pl file. You can then bring up the console window Vim starts and play with the command line exactly as Vim is running it.